# How to write xPath for Junit test case

Tags: xml, spring-mvc, xpath, junit, mockito

I have following XML string, 
How to write XPath to get value "rest/accounts/123"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> 
<account xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <atom:link rel="self" href="http://localhost/rest/accounts/123"/>
    <name>satya</name>
    <password>123</password> 
</account>
```

I am trying to write JUnit test case

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/rest/accounts/123")
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML))
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
            .andExpect(xpath("/account/atom:link/href()")
              .string(containsString("/rest/accounts/123")))
            .andExpect(xpath("/account/name/text()").string(equalTo("satya")));
```

but line

> MockMvcResultMatchers.xpath("/account/atom:link/href()").string(
>                                   Matchers.containsString("/rest/accounts/123")))

is throwing error.

As per suggestions I changed code as

```
 mockMvc.perform(
                MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/rest/accounts/123").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML))

                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
                .andExpect(
                        MockMvcResultMatchers.xpath("/account/atom:link/@href,").string(
                                Matchers.containsString("/rest/accounts/123")))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.xpath("/account/name/text()").string(Matchers.equalTo("satya")));

        // .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.links[*].href").exists());
    }
```

Junit test case giving error

> com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.domapi.XPathStylesheetDOM3Exception:
>   Prefix must resolve to a namespace: atom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `substring-after` function:

```
substring-after(//atom:link/@href, "http://localhost/")
```

Comment: After adding above changes still getting Junit test case error as shown above in problem

Comment: @Satya: I'm not familiar with the libraries you use. I replied to the original question. Maybe you need to register the `atom` namespace?